# Load multiple folder with PySimpleGui

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

Can there a one line for selecting multiple foldes path at once with PySimpleGUI

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
layout = [          
    [sg.Text('choose multiple folders and print at the console', size=(35, 1))],      
    [sg.Text('Your Folders', size=(15, 1), auto_size_text=False, justification='right'),      
        sg.InputText('Default Folder'), sg.FolderBrowse()],      
    [sg.Submit(tooltip='Click to submit this window'), sg.Cancel()]    
]      

event = sg.Window("select multiple folders by pressing CTRL +folder").Layout(layout).Read()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - This question requires more detail. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is called creating a minimal, reproducible example (reprex), a minimal, complete and verifiable example (mcve), or a minimal, workable example (mwe). - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Tanks. Please update the question

Comment: Not aware of any tkinter dialog box that allows selecting multiple folders which is what you need.  Side note - Window.Read returns 2 values - event, values.  If this is a "must have" feature, then you can implement it yourself using trees what you've enabled selecting multiple lines. You'll be implementing your own folder browser.  Alternatively, I don't know if Qt or Wx allow multiple folder selection.

Comment: thanks @MikeyB  I already did it with **  wx.lib.agw.multidirdialog ** and I would like to do it now with ** PySimpleGU I**. _it's an important feature of my application._

Comment: Well, you certainly could use it with PySimpleGUIWx.  Or PySimpleGUI.  This is a long discussion to have in comments.  If you want to see something like this in PySimpleGUI it makes sense to open an Issue on that project's GitHub, no?

Comment: Thanks @MikeyB for the time you gave me